# adding code that stores the formatted values as strings in the next row of the array?

Tags: java

I need to use a 2 dimensional array as part of the assignment.

1. I need to Declare variables at the beginning of the main method for a row counter and a rectangular array of strings that provides for 10 rows and 4 columns
2. After the code that calculates, formats, and displays the resutls for each calculation, add code that stores the formatted values as strings in the next row of the array ( you need to use the toString method of the integer class to store the years value).

I've already declared an array of 10x4 and a variable for a counter,
but I have a problem with  adding code that stores the formatted values as strings in the next row of the array ( you need to use the toString method of the integer class to store the years value).

heres what i've coded below for this question(2) which seems to print a list of nulls, how do I get my code to print the table? this code below seems to me as the one causing the issues is it correct? am a bit confused.

```
    FutureValueArray[counter][0] = Double.toString(monthlyInvestment);
    FutureValueArray[counter][1] = Double.toString(interestRate);
    FutureValueArray[counter][2] = Integer.toString(years);
    FutureValueArray[counter][3] = Double.toString(futureValue);
```

---

```
/*This is how my table should look like.
Inv/Mo. Rate Years Future Value
$100.00 8.0% 10 $18.416.57
$125.00 8.0% 10 $23,020.71*/


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[][] FutureValueArray = new String [10][4];
    int counter = 0;
    // display a welcome message
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Future Value Calculator");
    System.out.println();

    // perform 1 or more calculations
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {

        // get the input from the user
        System.out.println("DATA ENTRY");
        double monthlyInvestment = getDoubleWithinRange(sc,
            "Enter monthly investment: ", 0, 1000);
        double interestRate = getDoubleWithinRange(sc,
            "Enter yearly interest rate: ", 0, 30);
        int years = getIntWithinRange(sc,
            "Enter number of years: ", 0, 100);

        // calculate the future value
        double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate/12/100;
        int months = years * 12;
        double futureValue = calculateFutureValue(
            monthlyInvestment, monthlyInterestRate, months);

        // get the currency and percent formatters
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        percent.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);

        // format the result as a single string
        String results =
              "Monthly investment:\t"
                  + currency.format(monthlyInvestment) + "\n"
            + "Yearly interest rate:\t"
                  + percent.format(interestRate/100) + "\n"
            + "Number of years:\t"
                  +  years + "\n"
            + "Future value:\t\t"
                  + currency.format(futureValue) + "\n";

        // print the results
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("FORMATTED RESULTS");
        System.out.println(results);

        FutureValueArray[counter][0] = Double.toString(monthlyInvestment);
        FutureValueArray[counter][1] = Double.toString(interestRate);
        FutureValueArray[counter][2] = Integer.toString(years);
        FutureValueArray[counter][3] = Double.toString(futureValue);
        for(int i = 0; i < FutureValueArray.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < FutureValueArray[i].length; j++)
                System.out.println(FutureValueArray[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        // see if the user wants to continue
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.next();
        counter++;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine.

If you change

```
for(int i = 0; i < FutureValueArray.length; i++)
```

To

```
for(int i = 0; i <= counter; i++)
```

You won't print the nulls of the `FutureValueArray` rows that have not yet been set.

Also, it looks like you want to use the `System.out.print()` function inside that loop, rather than the `System.out.println()` function.

Comment: ok so I got got the counter to countrol the array so now how do I structure the out put so its in a table and not a list

Comment: I just edited in the suggestion of using the `System.out.print()` function -- are you looking for better formatting than that?

Comment: I want to display the table after the user enters no when prompted if they want to continue which ends the program so i moved the loop and put it after there response and then the table shows but i get one line after the result which is good of null null null null for each of the columns? is it the counter?

Comment: Yep, at that point you've incremented counter (which is fine).  Just change the middle condition of the `for` loop from `i<=counter` to `i<counter`.